# Adding several geom_signif annotations with step_increase, so they stack, without them changing the scale of the y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have several annotations, I have them stacking vertically with `step_increase`. The problem is that they tend to push the bars down and increase the scale of the y-axis, as if the position of the annotations mattered for the y-axis scale. Is there a way to make it so that the annotations for statistical significance don't push my bars down and change the y-axis scale? Perhaps by allowing them to go above the y-axis and just create a taller image?

Thank you much!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

tab_cond_phases <- data.table(
  condition = factor(c("WT_CTL", "MUT_CTL", "MUT1", "MUT2", "MUT3", "MUT4", "MUT5", "MUT6", "MUT7", "MUT8", "MUT9", "MUT10"),levels = c("MUT1", "MUT2", "MUT3", "MUT4", "MUT5", "MUT6", "MUT7", "MUT8", "MUT9","MUT10", "MUT_CTL", "WT_CTL")),
  Phase = rep("Dark", 12L),
  n_samples = rep(16, 12L),
  exp_sums = c(117021, 102318, 94897, 36513, 37749, 105215, 210122, 135288, 234010, 339447,368448, 353097),
  mean = c(7313.81, 6394.88, 5931.06, 2282.06, 2359.31, 6575.94, 13132.62, 8455.5,14625.62, 21215.44, 23028, 22068.56),
  median = c(6245, 4971.5, 4388.5, 266.5, 1217.5, 6372, 13760, 6585.5, 13133, 21116, 20260.5, 22605.5),
  sd = c(6115.21, 5692.08, 6429.4, 3900.59, 2687.43, 5074.05, 6197.2, 8966.1, 6457.71,7937.59, 11013.54, 7929.46),
  sem = c(1528.8, 1423.02, 1607.35, 975.15, 671.86, 1268.51, 1549.3, 2241.53, 1614.43,1984.4, 2753.39, 1982.36),
  CI_lower = c(4317.36, 3605.76, 2780.66, 370.77, 1042.47, 4089.65, 10096, 4062.11, 11461.35,17326.02, 17631.36, 18183.13),
  CI_upper = c(10310.27, 9183.99, 9081.47, 4193.35, 3676.16, 9062.22, 16169.25, 12848.89,17789.9, 25104.85, 28424.64, 25954)
)

ttest_compList_2 <- data.table(
  condition1 = c(
    "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "WT_CTL", "MUT1",
    "MUT2", "MUT3", "MUT4", "MUT5", "MUT6", "MUT7", "MUT8"
  ),
  condition2 = rep(
    c("MUT3", "MUT4", "MUT6", "MUT8", "MUT9", "MUT10", "MUT_CTL"),
    rep(c(1L, 9L), c(6L, 1L))
  ),
  t_statistic = c(
    2.774873432277503493282, 2.96690844738199510644, -2.673355010885269056331,
    -3.288537048164713816334, -5.549531525852588131897, -4.98966827756189,
    -5.89388706822980079636, -6.42302119046055, -6.323164321617654515251,
    -8.956305284062917593246, -9.416196716221929108315, -6.58284576953459,
    -3.551689562314324977166, -4.549276289293982422635, -2.911277697109336148884
  ),
  df = c(
    25.47213499519033774732, 20.58559587713055449854, 29.99468077334092797059,
    29.91134745364304592385, 28.16739007989376020191, 23.44612393212693746136,
    28.18030235117712223314, 27.21531378520303690038, 28.77096669326880373774,
    21.85775953797474357998, 18.40108543376586425211, 25.52022458844298213876,
    28.34528240046001101859, 29.55823360678268230117, 28.8185756390568279528
  ),
  p_value = c(
    0.01019826835762464335711, 0.007463280069633282734487,
    0.01203120869711024956694, 0.002580906002157091344573,
    6.070407674600901298725e-06, 4.543275243482094668569e-05,
    2.376863032630949551863e-06, 6.74159703895685e-07,
    6.825748237231438725770e-07, 9.117946512269315724117e-09,
    1.834868940768069092966e-08, 6.105714401838205257315e-07,
    0.001360954457791940580211, 8.534365001558583043589e-05,
    0.006876815484155762020491
  ),
  mean_cond1 = c(
    7313.8125, 7313.8125, 7313.8125, 7313.8125, 7313.8125, 7313.8125, 7313.8125,
    6394.875, 5931.0625, 2282.0625, 2359.3125, 6575.9375, 13132.625, 8455.5,
    14625.625
  ),
  mean_cond2 = rep(
    c(2282.0625, 2359.3125, 13132.625, 14625.625, 21215.4375, 23028, 22068.5625),
    rep(c(1L, 9L), c(6L, 1L))
  ),
  method = rep("Welch Two Sample t-test", 15L),
  pair = c(3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 30, 38, 45, 51, 56, 60, 63),
  xmin = c(2.8, 3.8, 5.8, 7.8, 8.8, 9.8, 10.8, 20.8, 29.8, 37.8, 44.8, 50.8, 55.8, 59.8, 62.8),
  xmax = c(3.2, 4.2, 6.2, 8.2, 9.2, 10.2, 11.2, 21.2, 30.2, 38.2, 45.2, 51.2, 56.2, 60.2, 63.2)
)

controls <- c("WT_CTL", "MUT_CTL")

ttest_compList_2 <- ttest_compList_2 %>%
  mutate(
    pair = as.numeric(factor(1:nrow(ttest_compList_2))),
    xmin = pair - 0.2,
    xmax = pair + 0.2
  ) %>%
  filter(p_value < 0.05, grepl(paste(controls, collapse = "|"), condition1) | grepl(paste(controls, collapse = "|"), condition2))

comparisons <- grep("^condition", names(ttest_compList_2), value = TRUE)
comparisonsdt <- ttest_compList_2[, ..comparisons, with = FALSE]

# Convert comparisonsdt to a list
comparison_list <- split(comparisonsdt, seq(nrow(comparisonsdt)))

# Convert each element of the list to a named vector
comparison_list <- lapply(comparison_list, function(x) {
  setNames(as.character(x), c("condition1", "condition2"))
})

comparison_list <- lapply(comparison_list, unname)

#This is for caluclating where the annotations should be on the y scale
max_row_index <- which.max(tab_cond_phases$mean)

max_sd_value <- tab_cond_phases[max_row_index, "sd"]

top <- max(tab_cond_phases$mean) + max_sd_value

top_plus <- as.integer(top + top*0.045)

p_mean_condition <- ggplot(tab_cond_phases, aes(x = condition, y = mean, fill = Phase, color = Phase)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Phase") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 25),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 25),
          axis.title=element_text(size=35,),
          legend.text = element_text(size=25),
          legend.title = element_text(size=30),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  labs(title = " ", x = "Conditions", y = "Means of Pixel Differences") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), color = "black") +
  geom_signif(
    comparisons = comparison_list,
    annotation = format(ttest_compList_2$p_value, scientific = TRUE, digits = 3), tip_length = 0.03, color = "black", textsize = 7,
    map_signif_level = TRUE,
    step_increase = 0.12
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I tried `coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, clip = "off")` and it has helped a bit, but it is still pushing the bars down. Is there a way to do these annotations so that they aren't considered part of the graph itself? Maybe that would work?
[image]

Comment: Untested, but I think you could use `coord_cartesian(ylim = ..., clip = "off")`. Might have to adjust the plot margin in the theme though.